# Is there a module to given node.js bindings to a c compiler?

Tags: c, node.js

I'm wondering if there's a c compiler with node bindings? Gcc maybe? I've looked but can't find anything.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/).

Comment: Good idea - npm's search doesn't have all the false positives google searching has

Comment: Any reason you can't just execute a compiler normally (e.g, using [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html))? Is there any deeper integration you need?

Comment: I'm interested in changing the mechanism I use to create installer packages. Right now I'm using https://github.com/fresheneesz/installer-maker and I want to explore other options to create single-file packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Elliot's suggestion I took a look at npm and found this one:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/tcc